# About GCC And MSVC Compatibility

Tags: gcc, visual-c++, compatibility

Does every source code that can compiled in GCC also can compiled in MSVC or they have some difference in implementation of C/C++ standard?

Comment: Yes and yes. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: obviously not for *every source code* because all compilers have [their](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html) [own](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html) [extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/microsoft-extensions-to-c-and-cpp?view=msvc-170).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You could list a few example that compile in one compiler but not on another or some method to port from GCC to MSVC. I think the question is specific enough.

Comment: it's still too broad, there are so many differences and extensions in both compilers